# HTTP Connection: Keep-Alive

Tags: http, keep-alive, http-1.1

I was looking at the [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10) spec and was looking at the part of the spec related to the 'Connection' header.  I noticed the the only token that is specified for the 'Connection' header is "close".  After a little digging I found that the 'Keep-Alive' token that is found in the 'Connection' header in many server implementations, including [Vim's](http://zamez.org/httplint?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vim.org) which is using Apache 2.2.3, is left over from [HTTP 1.0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.6.2).  Given the wide spread use of HTTP 1.1 how much value is there in adding Keep-Alive and similar inherited tokens from HTTP 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Some value; depends on the specific use.

> In HTTP 1.1, all connections are considered persistent unless declared otherwise.

In practice, implementations do what they want:

> When the client sends another request [after a HTTP Connection: Keep-Alive], it uses the same connection.
> This will continue until either the client or the server decides that
> the conversation is over, and one of them drops the connection.

So, it's really up to the implementers of the clients and servers to determine how long they keep the TCP connection open for. For example,

> The default connection timeout of Apache 2.0 httpd[2] is as little as
> 15 seconds[3] and for Apache 2.2 only 5 seconds.

It looks like SPDY will form the basis for the upcoming HTTP 2.0. This changes connection handling dramatically.

**Sources:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection#HTTP_1.1

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_2.0

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-http2-08